# Bing Map component in React

Tags: reactjs, components, bing-maps

I want create component to show bing map in React.js with TypeScript.
I know that there is very component in github for this purpose. but I want create this component from scratch for myself.
I created class in react and in `componentWillMount` function injected script tag to `head` of my html:

```
    componentWillMount() {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        var scriptURL = "<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?key=" + this.props.apiKey + "' ></script>";
        const scriptText = document.createTextNode(scriptURL);

        script.appendChild(scriptText);
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    }
```

when I want create map followed by [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/creating-and-hosting-map-controls/creating-a-basic-map-control)
 in `componentDidMount` function like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
        var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(this.mapElement);
    }
```

I get this error:

> Cannot find name 'Microsoft'.

how to I should import 'Microsoft' module to my component?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a minimalist implementation of React BingMaps component without any dependencies to BingMaps type definitions.

First a service for loading BingMaps API and `Microsoft` type are introduced:

```
export interface MapWindow extends Window {
  Microsoft: any;
}

declare let window: MapWindow;
export let Microsoft: any;


export function loadBingApi(key?: string): Promise<void> {
  const callbackName = "bingAPIReady";
  let url = `https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=${callbackName}`;
  if (key) {
    url += `&key=${key}`;
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    script.src = url;
    window[callbackName] = () => {
      Microsoft = window.Microsoft;
      resolve();
    };
    script.onerror = (error: Event) => {
      reject(error);
    };
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  });
}
```

Here is a Map component which accepts mapOptions as a props:

```
interface IMapProps {
    mapOptions?: any;
}

export default class BingMap extends React.Component<IMapProps, any> {
  private mapRef = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();

  public componentDidMount() {
    loadBingApi().then(() => {
      this.initMap();
    });
  }

  public render() {
    return <div ref={this.mapRef} className="map" />;
  }

  private initMap() {
    const map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(this.mapRef.current);
    if (this.props.mapOptions) {
      map.setOptions(this.props.mapOptions);
    }
    return map;
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<BingMap
    mapOptions={{
      center: [47.60357, -122.32945],
      credentials:
        "--BingMaps key goes here--"
    }}
/>
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-rjkub5)

Comment: Tanks Vadim Gremyachev. This is really what I want.

Comment: maybe explain about BingMapLoader.ts.
is it about react structure?
or it is only about BingMap component requirments?

Comment: Good to know! Regarding loader, it is a generic loader for Bing Maps API (with promise syntax) and framework agnostic (e.g. could be utilized with Vue as well)

Comment: Has anyone tried this using React Router?  It refuses to show pins that I'm putting on the map.  Used to, before I switched to using the router.

Answer (score 1):

`componentWillMount` will be deprecated in the next major release of React, it's better to place all the code to `componentDidMount`

Try this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?key=' + this.props.apiKey; 
    document.head.appendChild(script);

    script.onload = function() {
        this.map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(this.mapElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: because I using typeScript I get compile error that `Cannot find name 'Microsoft'.`
and it't doesn't matter where I use `new Microsoft.Maps.Map`

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with TypeScript, so I can't really help you there. What you can try to do as a temporary solution is add `declare var Microsoft: any;` to your file. But it's better to figure out how to import the type definitions

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
componentWillMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script"); // Creates <script></script>
    script.type = 'text/javascript'; // Set type
    script.src = 'https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?key=' + this.props.apiKey; // Set source
    document.head.appendChild(script); // Add script to page
}
```

Comment: my error is in `componentDidMount` function. where I want to create new instance from  `Microsoft.Maps.Map`

Comment: Is the script getting loaded correctly ? Do you see Microsoft in the global scope ? Because the way you created the script adds <script><script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?key=></script></script> to the header

Comment: because I using typeScript I get compile error.It is not yet runned in browser

Comment: Have a look here for the MS Bing map defenitions : https://github.com/microsoft/Bing-Maps-V8-TypeScript-Definitions

Comment: I have seen that before.but I couldn't import `Microsoft` module to my component in react !