# NPM Bingmaps for React.js

Tags: reactjs, bing-maps

Which packages are developers using to integrate Bing maps into their React.js applications?

I have looked at react-bingmaps but this package is now deprecated (npm WARN deprecated react-bingmaps@3.6.1)

So looking for something that we can use to integrate Bing maps into a React.js application which isn't deprecated.

Comment: A quick google gives https://github.com/milespratt/bingmaps-react and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58130625/bing-map-component-in-react

Answer (score 0):

In addition to https://github.com/milespratt/bingmaps-react you may also want to consider [Azure Maps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/azure-maps/) (Microsoft's newer enterprise mapping platform). It also has a react library, and it is maintained by Microsoft: https://github.com/Azure/react-azure-maps

Here are some additional resource on Azure Maps:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/
- https://samples.azuremaps.com/